# JNDI Obtain the size of a LDAP search without retrieving all the data

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I need to know how many users and groups are in my LDAP directory. The search looks fairly simple:

> (| (objectClass=group)(objectClass=user))

The problem is that the API is very limited. I can only get a `NamingEnumeration<SearchResult>` and it doesn't have a count. I didn't find any functions we can use, like the `count` in SQL.

Is there any way I can get this count without having to retrieve the full query and count the results with a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to do this was to make a query for an empty attribute array, then loop and increment a counter.